# How to append and save CSV file name after running code

Tags: r

I have a csv file I usually load like `"01082019.csv"`. After running my code, I would like to save this file as `"01082019Analysis"`. My question is, how can I parse the original file name and take out the `"01092019"` and append that to `"analysis.csv"`, so the exported saved filed will be `"01082019Analysis"`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full code and exact problem. Have you tried `?write.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

You can paste them together then remove the middle `.csv` with `sub()`.  Then we can capitalize `analysis` by capturing the `a` and using `\\U\\1` for replacement.

```
x <- "01082019.csv"
y <- "analysis.csv"

sub("\\.csv(a?)", "\\U\\1", paste0(x, y), perl=TRUE)
# [1] "01082019Analysis.csv"
```

If both `.csv` need to be removed, use `gsub()`.

```
gsub("\\.csv(a?)", "\\U\\1", paste0(x, y), perl=TRUE)
# [1] "01082019Analysis"
```